# bash: run "find --exec ..." command with terminating "\;", all stored in variable?

Tags: linux, bash, find, escaping, exec

I'm trying to find a way in a bash script to build a `find` command with a `-exec` stored in a variable, and I can't get the terminating `\;` to be recognized correctly if it's part of the variable.

I can work around it by adding the `\;` when I invoke the command via the variable:

```
local all_the_things=($($cmd \;))
```

I'm not sure though how that might interact when `$cmd` stores a different command (there are several quite different contexts with different ways to get the list I need, only one of which is via a `find` command).

E.g., if I have the following directory and files,

```
$ ls -l /tmp/dir1
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 joeuser  joemama  0 Jul 15 10:19 1A
-rw-r--r--  1 joeuser  joemama  0 Jul 15 10:19 1B
```

I want to send each of the filenames `1A` and `1B` to `basename`. Here's several ways I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd="find /tmp/dir1 -exec basename {} \;"
echo; echo "One slash: $cmd"
$cmd

cmd="find /tmp/dir1 -exec basename {} \\;"
echo; echo "Two slashes: $cmd"
$cmd

cmd="find /tmp/dir1 -exec basename {} \\\;"
echo; echo "Three slashes: $cmd"
$cmd

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
# The first of these gets the desired result, but I want the "\;" in $cmd.
# The second shows that the "\;" is being treated as part of the -exec
# option, not its terminator.

cmd="find /tmp/dir1 -exec basename {}"
echo; echo "No slash, will add extra '\;': $cmd"
$cmd \;

cmd="find /tmp/dir1 -exec echo {} \;"
echo; echo "Command is echo, not basename. One slash, will add extra '\;': $cmd"
$cmd \;
```

And the output:

```
$ /tmp/gofind1 

One slash: find /tmp/dir1 -exec echo {} \;
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"

Two slashes: find /tmp/dir1 -exec echo {} \;
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"

Three slashes: find /tmp/dir1 -exec echo {} \\;
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"

No slash, will add extra '\;': find /tmp/dir1 -exec echo {}
dir1
1A
1B

Command is echo, not basename. One slash, will add extra '\;': find /tmp/dir1 -exec echo {} \;
/tmp/dir1 \;
/tmp/dir1/1A \;
/tmp/dir1/1B \;
```

Is there a way to properly escape the "\;" so it can be stored in `$cmd`? Or can I rest assured that adding the `\;` inside the `($( ... ))` won't break something else later?

Comment: You **cannot** do this in general. This is [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Etan, that was a fantastically useful link, thanks much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store them into a BASH array:

```
cmd=(find /tmp/dir1 -exec basename {} \;)

# then execute it as:
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Another possibility is to use BASH function for this:

```
cmdfn() {
   find /tmp/dir1 -exec basename {} \;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Either we use a variable or an array, we should 'eval' to get the correct output

```
cmd="find /tmp/dir1 -exec basename {} \;"
eval "${cmd}"
```